# Using Spring/ Hibernate /Jackson. Getting error -- Could not read JSON: Could not initialize class exception

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

We are using the combination of Jackson, spring and hibernate in our application.
Below code I am listing is working fine

Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = ServiceEndpoints.MyService, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody   
public MyResponse updateEntity(final HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody final MyEntity myEntity )  {
//Service Call  
}
```

Entity

```
 @Entity
 public class MyEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Column
private String metaTags;

    public String getMetaTags() {
    return metaTags;
}

public void setMetaTags(String metaTags) {          
    this.metaTags = metaTags;
}
```

servlet-contect.xml

```
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"
                   class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <ref bean="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The above code works Fine. We get data from UI, it gets converted from JSON to entity and we are able to save the same.
But then i added  a code to clean some charatcers from the Entity field  as shown below

```
   public void setMetaTags(String comments) {       
    this.metaTags = MyClassWithStaticMethods.OnesuchStaticMethod(metaTags); 

}
```

I get the below exception

```
Could not read JSON: Could not initialize class MyClassWithStaticMethods (through reference chain: MyEntity["metaTags"]); 
 nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Could not initialize class MyClassWithStaticMethods (through reference chain: MyEntity["metaTags"])
```

Now i did go through some links like this one
http://cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html

but this link is not really related to my problem.
Can any one please help

Comment: `public void setMetaTags(String comments) {       
    this.metaTags = MyClassWithStaticMethods.OnesuchStaticMethod(metaTags); 

}` this could be making it a bad JSON and JSON is having trouble parsing it. You may try to see text representation of JSON before and after this method call.

Comment: The problem is there in the class MyClassWithStaticMethods. Could you put in the contents of this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was multiple versions of the same jar which was in turn used by "MyClassWithStaticMethods" (Thanks @Abhijith Nagarajan for asking to look into it).

My method was using guava API and another part of the application was using the old google-collections. These two were creating the problem.

Regards